# Which library to add as dependency?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Newbie to dialog flow, trying to integrate the java library.

Confused between the two dependencies below:

1) https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/libraries/java

2) https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/dialogflow/v2

The first one says java client library and the second one says api client library for java.
Which is the correct dependency to interact with the dialog flow

Comment: What kind of interactions with Dialogflow are you expecting? These libraries support things like editing intents and entities via REST API

Comment: I just need to hit the dialogflow endpoint with the queryInput to get response for the question.